# Does jasmine build the app completly before testing?

Tags: typescript, jasmine

When I run my jasmine tests with a script like this:

```
"test-backend": "ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine --config=jasmine_backend.json"
```

I wonder, if beforehand the typescript project gets built (similar to what tsc does). Logically it should, because, why should it be able to run the tests properly then?

Background for this question is that I am not sure if I should add a separate tsc to my github checks when a PR gets opened. I already have a github check which executes the backend unit test script.

Comment: **No, only files imported in the test get processed** (of course sub-imports too), no matter if testing Angular, React or even backend's Node.js code.